# Invalid Encryption Declaration - Play Store app rejection

Tags: android, http, https, google-play

> Issue found: Invalid Encryption Declaration on your Data safety form
> We’ve detected discrepancies between how your app collects and shares
> user data and what was declared in your app’s Data safety form. All
> apps are required to complete an accurate Data safety form that
> discloses their data collection and sharing practices; this is
> required even if your app does not collect any user data.
>
> You have declared that user data is encrypted in transit in your app’s
> Data safety form, and we’ve detected unencrypted network traffic that
> may carry user data off device. Best industry standards, such as TLS
> (Transport Layer Security) and HTTPS, should be followed to safely
> encrypt your app’s data in transit.
>
> Issue details
>
> We found an issue in the following area(s):
>
> Version code 1: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section:
> "http://xx.xx.xx.xx" About the Data safety section in Google Play User
> Data policy All developers must complete a clear and accurate Data
> safety section for every app detailing collection, use, and sharing of
> user data. Your app must be in compliance with this policy. If your
> app continues to be non-compliant, your app may face additional
> enforcement actions in the future.
>
> Please make changes to align your app’s Data safety form with the
> app’s behavior. This can be done by either:

all place use https but server ip not https getting app rejected faceing.

Comment: The URL for API should be `HTTPS` instead of `HTTP`.

Comment: yes but return play store return server ip with http

Comment: So you're saying you have **no** instances of `http://xx.xx.xx.xx`? Even then, although it can be done securely, using a bare IP address with HTTPS is a red flag.